# GKE create a private cluster failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following [this topic](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-kubernetes-engine-private-clusters-with-net-proxies) to Creating GKE private clusters with network proxies for controller access, it stuck at create a private cluster via run command:

```
gcloud container clusters create frobnitz  \
    --master-ipv4-cidr=172.16.0.64/28 \
    --network k8s-proxy \
    --subnetwork=subnet-cluster \
    --enable-ip-alias \
    --enable-private-nodes \
    --enable-private-endpoint \
    --master-authorized-networks $CLIENT_IP/32 \
    --enable-master-authorized-networks
```

Get error message:
All cluster resources were brought up, but: component "kube-apiserver" from endpoint "gke-d28547e410cb4d089d27-b74d" is unhealthy.

Does anyone have same experience? How to fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the format, had you tried this?:

`gcloud container clusters create "frobnitz" --zone "us-central1-c" --enable-private-nodes --enable-private-endpoint --master-ipv4-cidr "172.16.0.64/28" --enable-ip-alias --network "projects/gke-gen/global/networks/k8s-proxy" --subnetwork "projects/gke-gen/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/subnet-cluster" --enable-master-authorized-networks --master-authorized-networks 10.3.8.5/32`

Feel free to change `10.3.8.5`, `gke-gen` and `zone / us-central1-c` to your liking, as long as you don't have `Deny` GCP Firewall rules you should be fine without any.

Comment: I just re-run that command again, and cluster was created without any error.

Comment: I am glad this helped, I will post this as an answer in order to help other users, if you can mark that one as "accepted" it will help other users to recognize that one helped you

Answer (score 0):

Full needed command:

```
gcloud container clusters create "frobnitz" \
    --zone "us-central1-c" --enable-private-nodes \
    --enable-private-endpoint --master-ipv4-cidr "172.16.0.64/28" \
    --enable-ip-alias --network "projects/gke-gen/global/networks/k8s-proxy" \
    --subnetwork "projects/gke-gen/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/subnet-cluster" \
    --enable-master-authorized-networks --master-authorized-networks 10.3.8.5/32
```

Feel free to change `10.3.8.5`, `gke-gen` and `zone / us-central1-c` to your liking, as long as you don't have `Deny` GCP Firewall rules you should be fine without any.